# How to delete many documents from MongoDB in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How to delete many documents from DB at once without using filters. I have list of objects and i want to remove them all similarly like in insertMany i can pass my new objects.

f.e `db.GetCollection<Collection>("Test").InsertMany(objectsToAdd);`

Comment: I dont think its possible without using filters.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee so maybe there is a way to limit the number of entities that i want to delete ?

Comment: Define "without using filters". `remove` without filter deletes all documents.

Comment: You can use the FindOptions<T> class to limit the batch size like: FindOptions<BsonDocument> options = new FindOptions<BsonDocument>
{
  BatchSize = 5,
  NoCursorTimeout = false
};

Comment: You can use the FindOneAndDelete<T> method of MongoDB.Driver 2.4.4 from Nuget package to find one item and delete it.